# PHP how to remove or normalise the hidden special characters

Tags: php, preg-match, special-characters

I'm trying to test a few keywords from this [periodic table wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table#Overview), such as,

```
Zirco­nium
```

[The test](http://writecodeonline.com/php/),

```
var_dump(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/', trim('Zirco­nium')));
```

it will be rewritten to,

```
var_dump(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/', trim('ZircoÂ­nium'))); // note that 'Â­' suddenly appears
```

and return the result below,

```
int(0) // I would like to get int(1) acutally.
```

But I can't see this hidden `Â­` in the word I tested. So how can I **remove** these **hidden** letters or normalise them?

Comment: Copy your code in a notepad and appears a "-" like `var_dump(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/', trim('Zirco-­nium'))); `

Comment: Delete the part `trim('Zirco­nium')` and write manually and it works

http://i.gyazo.com/1c3748226aedec5ad72fbd178b485ccf.png

Comment: Im copypasting the element's name from wikipedia in a notepad and appears the "-", Copy the names without the format and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this..

```
preg_replace('/[^\p{Latin}\d ]/u', '', $str);
```